# Models and EF are making them plural - hauler/haulers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This has happened twice on the same project. I'm using MVC/VS2015 community and I'm adding 2 classes: hauler and sale.

```
namespace CarThingy2.Models
{
    public class Sale
    {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int CoNbr { get; set; }
            public int Locn { get; set; }
            public int Ticket { get; set; }
            public int Haul_Code { get; set; }       
    }
}
```

so I go to save - then I add the controller, and everything's good except I change the controller "title" (it was scaffolded as "SalesController") to SaleController. Run the project and it gives me an error about "it can't find dbo.Sales" in the "InnerException".  I ended up having to enable-migrations, add-migration addsomethingelse and then finally update-database. TWICE (once for hauler, once for sale)!

Am I doing something wrong that grabs the "pluralized" name? This has happened to me before and I would least like an explanation as to why. The weirdest thing now is that the website will work, but the Tables ARE PLURAL (Haulers and Sales).

Answer (score 0):

So were the tables originally called 'dbo.Sale' and 'dbo.Hauler'?

EF default convention is to use singular entity names and plural table names. You can manually specify the table name in the mapping though.

Note - now that you've added migrations, this will trigger another migration (or just delete the Migrations folder in the project and the dbo._MigrationHistory table in the database if you don't want migrations).

In the DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Hauler>().ToTable("Hauler");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>().ToTable("Sale");
}
```

If you have an existing database with all singular names, you can globally remove the pluralization convention in the above method as well:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Or via attribute on the entity:

```
[Table("Sale")]
public class Sale 
{

}
```